# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in angular4 Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

When I execute my code I got "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" error in console but anyhow "replace()" does its job.

Here is my code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'questionPipe'
})
export class QuestionPipePipe implements PipeTransform {
  public pattern: RegExp = /<question id=(.*?)><\/question>/g;

  transform(value: string): string {
    let newValue = value.replace(this.pattern, "________");
    return newValue;
  }

}
```

Comment: How are you using the pipe in the html ? should be `value|questionPipe`

Comment: Same problem, only other method being invoked on the string argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time the Pipe runs, the value is undefined. Just check beforehand that it has a value:

```
return value ? value.replace(this.pattern, "________") : value;
```